# nvprof: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libcupti.so.12: version `libcupti.so.12' not found (required by nvprof)

Tags: cuda

I want to use nvprof which in /usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin

but when I input nvprof in console, it show me this error:

```
nvprof: error while loading shared libraries: libcupti.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

so I use ln command to link this library into /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64 which has been set in $PATH

```
sudo ln -s /usr/local/cuda-11.7/extras/CUPTI/lib64/libcupti.so.11.7 /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libcupti.so.12
```

then I try nvprof again and the console report this error

```
nvprof: /usr/local/cuda-11.7/lib64/libcupti.so.12: version `libcupti.so.12' not found (required by nvprof)
```

Does anyone know this error?

If nvprof need cuda12 and my cuda version is 11.7, so the library version is too low?

Do I need reinstall cuda with version 12?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have a CUDA 12 toolkit installed on your computer. It could be located in packages installed by Anaconda. In order to use nvprof from your 11.7 toolkit in `/usr/local/cuda-11.7/`, use the command below:

```
$ /usr/local/cuda-11.7/bin/nvprof
======== Error: no application specified.
```